# Best way to unwrap optional type

Tags: swift

I have a situation

```
let a: Int? = getFromSomewhere()
if a ＝= nil {
    return
}
let b = a!
```

I don't like too many layer. But I think this is not elegant.
Do you have more elegant way?

Comment: What does "elegant" even mean? — Why would you return if `a` is _not_ `nil`? Why would you force-unwrap `a` if it _is_ `nil`? Your code makes no sense. You would crash if you ran that code.

Comment: My mistake, it should be equal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Omit `a`, omit the nil check, omit the force-unwrap; one line:

```
guard let b = getFromSomewhere() else {return}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `guard` or `if let` to unwrap optionals:

so instead of :

```
if a != nil {
    return
}
let b = a! 

if let a = getFromSomewhere() { 
 // Do what you want with a
} else {
  // a is nil
}
```

And with a guard statement :

```
guard let a = getFromSomewhere() else {
    NSLog("error a is nil")
    return 
} 

// You can use a now if it's not nil
```